# New Relic with graalvm

Tags: newrelic, graalvm-native-image

I am developing spring boot 3 app with native graalvm support.
For that I want to integrate Newrelic with it.
Any idea on integrating new Relic with graalvm.

I tried to add new Relic agent by using --jvmargs option.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the New Relic Java agent does not work in native mode as the native application does not support the javaagent argument.

As @Hillel pointed out, you can use it Graal's JVM mode.

<s>You should be able to use New Relic's micrometer registry though.
https://github.com/newrelic/micrometer-registry-newrelic</s>

New Relic's micrometer registry has been discontinued in favor of OpenTelemetry's Micrometer Shim.

See a configuration example [here](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-opentelemetry-examples/tree/main/java/sdk-nr-config).